# Appbar hide/show like iOS Style

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-appbar

I want to show AppBar when the first child of ListVIew is scroll over like iOS style (particularly behavior in native Books app in iOS). A lot of Apps in iOS do have this feature so I think it is a common behavior in iOS. But I don't know how to apply it to Flutter with Material Style. Does anyone know a solution to this one?
The GIF below shows the behavior that I want to implement:
[Behavior with Appbar iOS Style](https://giphy.com/gifs/TgVDOF2KD0s2OIVsle)

Comment: You can use `SliverAppBar`  e.g: https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-collapsing-toolbar-sliver-app-bar-14b858e87abe

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it in MaterialApp by using  SliverAppBar with CustomScrollView in the body section of scaffold.
You can use SliverAppBar instead of normal appBar
The widgets which you will be using should be inside the
SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              [ ]))

```
return Scaffold(


  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        expandedHeight: 300,
        pinned: true,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          title: Text(
           "Reading Now",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.end,
          ),
          background: Image.network(
              https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lN0b.png,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
        ),
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
          [


//widgets which you are going to use inside the listview you can use them in 
//sliverList
                ]
              ),//SliverChildListDelegate
          ),//SliverList
    ],//sliver Widgets
  ),//customScrollView
```

Comment: It is much similar to https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-collapsing-toolbar-sliver-app-bar-14b858e87abe

Comment: But the difference lies in the ScorllView used 
Here I am usinf CustomScrollView instead of NestedScrollVIew

Comment: In the background of AppBar you can use any color of your choice or  use  the image